# Trouble with conditional statement

Tags: python, algorithm

I am working on an algorithm, but I'm stuck at the final step. I'm trying to print an additional "column" based on the conditions that I have defined but cant figure out how to do it. So far I have:

```py
running_count = 0
consecutive_passes = 0
strikes = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
  
  if df.FINALS[i] == "PASS":
    running_count += 1
    consecutive_passes += 1
    if consecutive_passes >= 11 and consecutive_passes <= 17:
      strikes = 2
      print(running_count, df.FINALS[i], consecutive_passes, strikes)
    if consecutive_passes <= 10:
      print(running_count, df.FINALS[i], consecutive_passes, strikes)
  
  if df.FINALS[i] == "FAIL":
    running_count += 1
    consecutive_passes = 0
    strikes -= 1
    print(running_count, df.FINALS[i], consecutive_passes, strikes)
```

```
OUTPUT:
1 PASS 1 0
2 PASS 2 0
3 PASS 3 0
4 PASS 4 0
5 PASS 5 0
6 PASS 6 0
7 PASS 7 0
8 PASS 8 0
9 PASS 9 0
10 PASS 10 0
11 PASS 11 2
12 PASS 12 2
13 PASS 13 2
14 PASS 14 2
15 FAIL 0 1
16 PASS 1 1
17 PASS 2 1
18 PASS 3 1
19 PASS 4 1
20 PASS 5 1
21 PASS 6 1
22 PASS 7 1
23 PASS 8 1
24 FAIL 0 0
25 PASS 1 0
26 PASS 2 0
27 PASS 3 0
28 PASS 4 0
29 PASS 5 0
30 PASS 6 0
31 PASS 7 0
32 PASS 8 0
33 PASS 9 0
34 PASS 10 0
35 PASS 11 2
```

I need the output to look like the following, but I cant quite understand which condition to add to get the output to look the way I need it to.

```
1 PASS 1 0 100
2 PASS 2 0 100
3 PASS 3 0 100
4 PASS 4 0 100
5 PASS 5 0 100
6 PASS 6 0 100
7 PASS 7 0 100
8 PASS 8 0 100
9 PASS 9 0 100
10 PASS 10 0 100
11 PASS 11 2 50
12 PASS 12 2 50
13 PASS 13 2 50
14 PASS 14 2 50
15 FAIL 0 1 50
16 PASS 1 1 50
17 PASS 2 1 50
18 PASS 3 1 50
19 PASS 4 1 50
20 PASS 5 1 50
21 PASS 6 1 50
22 PASS 7 1 50
23 PASS 8 1 50
24 FAIL 0 0 50
25 PASS 1 0 100
26 PASS 2 0 100
27 PASS 3 0 100
28 PASS 4 0 100
29 PASS 5 0 100
30 PASS 6 0 100
31 PASS 7 0 100
32 PASS 8 0 100
33 PASS 9 0 100
34 PASS 10 0 100
35 PASS 11 2 50
```

The way I was planning on determining the last column was to access it via a python dictionary based on the `strikes` count and the `consecutive count`.

```py
rate = {
    100: list(range(1, 11)),
    50: list(range(11, 17)),
    33: list(range(17, 26))
}
```

If someone can help that would be great. P.S. I plan to append all of the results to a list and save it to a Pandas `DataFrame`. Thanks.

Comment: How do you determine what should go in the last column ?

Comment: I was planning to add it via a python dictionary. I added it to the question if that help. Thanks

Comment: It is still not clear what logic you would like to apply to make the last column

Answer (score 0):

you can construct a list of the values you want to append (e.g.

```
lastcol=[100] * 10 + [50] * 6 + [33] * 9
```

and append that to the dataframe

```
df['lastcol']=lastcol
```

Comment: I wanted to added it inside the for loop to match the conditions.